# Can I use a “refurbished” Windows 7 license key on a virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, license

I am a software developer and recently purchased a Windows 7 Home Premium license and media labeled as "Intended for distribution with a refurbished PC".

Does the license allow installation in a virtual machine for my personal use?

See also:

[what does intended for distribution with a refurbished pc mean?](https://superuser.com/questions/691653/what-does-intended-for-distribution-with-a-refurbished-pc-mean)

Comment: You can probably use the key, but the key also probably has a limited amount of uses. Microsoft play fair like that.

Answer (score 0):

This type of license need an old Windows license sticker on the refurbished PC. Also this license is bound to a hardware box only.